# How do I resolve a many to many connection error in Prisma Rust Client?

Tags: rust, prisma, tauri

I have models Employer & Member with a pivot table MembersOnEmployers using Prisma Client Rust.

The models are structured as follows:

```
    model Employer {
      id                  Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
      name                String               @unique
    }

    model Member {
      id                 Int                  @id @default(autoincrement())
      title              String?
      name               String
    }

    model MembersOnEmployers {
      Employer    Employer?             @relation(fields: [employerId], references: [id])
      employerId  Int
      Member      Member?               @relation(fields: [memberId], references: [id])
      memberId    Int
      transitions TransitionOnMembers[]

      @@id([employerId, memberId])
    }
```

I am creating a member and linking to employer as follows:

```
    client
    .member()
    .create(
        member_data[0].to_string(),
        member_data[1].to_string(),
        vec![
            prisma::member::employers::connect(
                vec![
                    prisma::employer::id::equals(employer_id.clone()),
                ]
            ),
        ],
    )
    .exec()
    .await
    .unwrap();
```

The code cannot compile and I am getting the following errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `prisma::members_on_employers::UniqueWhereParam: From<prisma::employer::UniqueWhereParam>` is not satisfied
   --> src\main.rs:74:25
    |
74  |                         prisma::employer::id::equals(employer_id.clone()),
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<prisma::employer::UniqueWhereParam>` is not implemented for `prisma::members_on_employers::UniqueWhereParam` 
    |
note: required by a bound in `prisma::employer::id::equals`
   --> src\prisma.rs:916:26
    |
916 |         pub fn equals<T: From<UniqueWhereParam>>(value: i32) -> T {
    |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `prisma::employer::id::equals`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `app` due to previous error
```

How can the errors be resolved?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?